# Jazz style with examples?

Tags: jazz

There are a ton of sites that list out all sorts of different jazz subgenres, for example, this one: http://www.jazzmusicarchives.com/musicguides

However, I have not found a good resource that pairs the name of a style with a recording that exemplifies that style, which would go a long way to understand what jazz styles are what.

Does anyone know of a resource like this?

Comment: The jazz tree helped me tons of times:
http://www.123posters.com/images/music/m-usajazz1d.jpg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably a couple of reasons why such lists don't abound is that:

1. Any such list is always going to be tremendously incomplete. In general you can't get a sound perspective on a style with just one or two examples.
2. You're never going to get general consensus about the selection you may pick in such an attempt.

Anyway, I understand your perplexity and you have got to start somewhere. Here's a possible seed for your exploration:

- Early Jazz

  - Louis Armstrong, *Hotter Than That* - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tAlrpx40UnE
- Swing

  - Count Basie, *One O'Clock Jump* - https://youtu.be/08jyOwx96Ig
  - Duke Ellington, *Take the A Train* - https://youtu.be/cb2w2m1JmCY
- Bebop

  - Dizzy Gillespie and Charlie Parker, *Shaw 'Nuff* -  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SNHUZmTmj-8
- Cool

  - Dave Brubeck, *Take Five* - https://youtu.be/tT9Eh8wNMkw
  - Miles Davis, Birth of the Cool - https://youtu.be/c1HK8Rma4Bo
- Hard Bop

  - Art Blakey, *Moanin'* - https://youtu.be/Cv9NSR-2DwM
  - Horace Silver, *Song For My Father* - https://youtu.be/CWeXOm49kE0
- Modal

  - Miles Davies, *So What* - https://youtu.be/ylXk1LBvIqU
  - Johan Coltrane, *Impression* - https://youtu.be/03juO5oS2gg
- John Coltrane, *Giant Steps* - https://youtu.be/30FTr6G53VU - I don't think this example fits in any specific subgenre, but it's a seminal work that pivoted the transition from previous hard bop and modal genres to future avant garde and free approaches.
- Free

  - John Coltrane, *Ascension* - https://youtu.be/_FyGClOb690
- Fusion

  - Herbie Hancock, *Headhunters* - https://youtu.be/GAlejqkd-gg
- Neoclassical

  - Wynton Marsalis (and others), Jungle Blues - https://youtu.be/jM7BzW6vhl8

If you really want to better your understanding of Jazz and its different styles, this is just a molecule on the tip of the iceberg :-). There are a couple of online free courses, that may get you on a faster track (I recommend [Jazz Appreciation](https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:UTAustinX+UT.8.03x+1T2016/info) from edx), but a good book with a discography section will surely be of great help too. The JazzMusicArchives also has pointers to many artists and specific records, but you have to dig deeper in the specific sections.

Comment: Thank you! The course seems perfect for what I'm looking for, but unfortunately enrollment is closed right now. I'll check back periodically, but thank you for this list!